# Remote SubversionSVN connection to Unix Server

Tags: delphi, svn, unix

Having installed TurtoiseSVN locally (local repository, no server) for my Delphi projects, i now want to share my updates via internet. To make it possible i did install Subversion (version 1.6) on an Apache Unix server (RedHat, VDS Hosting plan with Sphera) and created a repository folder at that place. The server is running well but i'm a bit lost at that point:

What are my best options to import the projects to the Unix repository, the easiest will be to clone the local repository to the one on the Unix machine? - ideally i would like them both synchro. What is the best tool to manage the Unix Subversion server and its repository (right now i'm using SSH Explorer) and best tool to checkout/import/export files on the repository of that server?

Tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem.

General remote connection script from a Windows SubversionSVN to a unix Subversion server:

```
svn+ssh://<username>@<hostname>:<port>/<location of the SVN repository>
```

Better, lets have username and password parameters added to TortoisePlink.exe, Open Explorer file window, right-click in the file section (get a pop-up), choose: TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> "Network" Pane-> SSH Client.

exemple: 'TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe -l username -pw password'

now the connection will be:

`svn+ssh://@<hostname>:<port>/<location of the SVN repository>`  ... no need to add username and no password asked for.

Comment: is there really a `@` necessary between `//` and `<hostname>` in the second URL?

Comment: Note: if you use a connection through Putty with public/private key than no need to have the @ Exemple: svn+ssh://PuttyconnectionName/<path to repository>

Answer (score 7):

To copy the local repository to the server, you can use `svnadmin dump` to backup the local repo including all revisions to a portable backup file. On the target server, use `svnadmin load` to install the backup.

See '[Repository Maintenance - Migrating Repository Data Elsewhere](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate)' in the documentation.

If you have the server running, there is no need for the local repository anymore. If you really want to keep and synchronize a local repository with the server, you can use the `svnadmin hotcopy` command.

Comment: Thanks - I can't get the dump command working. Lets say local project repos is: file:///E:/mirror/Acctwrks2010/trunk (many subdirectories) and repos on unix server is http://someaddress.com/var/svn/repos/acctwrks/trunk - what will be the dump command?

Comment: If you enter `svnadmin help dump` you can see the documentation and syntax: `svnadmin dump REPOS_PATH` - for example `svnadmin dump E:\mirror\ > dumpfile` will dump to the file `dumpfile` which you then can move to the server (for example using FTP) and there load using svnadmin load. However I have not worked with serverless (file based) repositories so much. Maybe I'll try and come back later.

Comment: May be i could just ftp the files to my unix server and then svn import the files to the repository from there?

Comment: May be i could just ftp the files to the unix machine and then import those files to the subversion repository with svnadmin? (i recall you that i command the subversion server on the unix machine with SSHExplorer from my Windows location). Is there any tool that will allow me to manage my files locally (windows), adding them to the distant Unix repository instead of locally like TutoiseSVN does?

Comment: You can import the local files directly to the remote server with TortoiseSVN. First export the projects, to make sure that they have no .svn subfolders. Then use the import coomand in TortoiseSVN and enter the target address like `http://server/project/trunk`

Comment: Thanks, i will give a try and report.

Comment: No luck, i get an OPTIONS of : 200 () OK" error ... That might be related to some restriction issue from the unix server? May be TurtoiseSVN is the the tool to do the import and some command line will do better?

Comment: I have tried with the TortoiseSVN command line svn import .. and same result: OPTIONS of ...:200()OK - !! Authentication issue ?

Comment: Having 'svn://server/project/trunk' instead of http://server/project/trunk  give me a connection (firewall notice) but refused by the unix server!

Comment: i now connect and get this message: No repository found in 'svn+ssh://server/project/trunk' !!!!!

Comment: There is no way i can connect - after spending 2 days on the subject i'm ready to pay someone to establish a connection and setup that subversion repository.

Comment: There are free Subversion hosting services on the web like ProjectLocker (500 MB), Springloops (100 MB) or XP-Dev, and many others. Maybe not the perfect solution but good for tests.

Comment: Another idea: install a Subversion server on your client machine only to learn the basics. Some packages like VisualSVN server are easy to set up. Free standard edition here: http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Comment: Thanks - i have paid to get a subversion server on unix machine :( but they can't give me help to connect remotly! I do connect locally using svn+ssh://username@domain.com/var/www/html/svn/repos/p_account. I unable to connect remotly using SubversionSVN. I guest i just do not have the good connection script.

Comment: The only result i get is to see my IP blocked at their server for abuse! Naturally i have tried true path svn+ssh://username@domain.com/var/www/html/svn/repos/p_account - no success. Then short path svn+ssh://username@domain.com/svn/repos/p_account - still nothing! I have followed those advices - http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2004-03/0253.shtml - (point 6 and 7): 6 is OK but for 7 ... can't connect. I'm short of idea.